# Get Site Certificate ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, certificate, client-certificates

I create multiple site in IIS. These IIS sites has same physical path. Because they have same source code some times i need to distinguish between them.
I use this solution :

> I use separate certificate for each site and i want to get certificate in  controller. for this purpose i use this code:

```
if (Request.ClientCertificate.IsPresent)
        {cert = new X509Certificate2(this.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);}
```

but `Request.ClientCertificate.IsPresent` Has `false` value.
I should mentioned that i create certificate with `makecert.exe` and install it on root certificate path. the certificate also presents in browser.
finally i need the running site certificate. I don't know how can i get that certificate?

Please give me your insights.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I use IIS 7 on Windows 7

Comment: Please help me. I need your answer

Comment: Am I the First One in the world face to this Problem!!!!!!!!!!!?????
Or This is one of the insolvable problem in the word????????????!!!!!!!!

Comment: `finally i need the running site certificate`. You mean that you need to get the client certificate in the code, right? I am trying to do the same, and I too get the `.IsPresent` being `false`. Did you ever figure this out?